# After adding cors to nodeJS returning internal server error

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm stuck with cors issue.I have to get data on another port, so i need cors dependency. there appears problem. everything works fine without `app.use(cors());` but when i add it, server returns `internal server error` Error code 500

```
const Koa = require("koa");
const Router = require("koa-router");

const app = new Koa();
const router = Router();

const data = require("./data.json");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

router.get("/", async (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = data;
});

app.use(router.routes());

app.listen(3001);
```

Comment: It's not related to cors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `koajs/cors` instead of `cors` and it solved problem